# I can't find the System.Media namespace in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, media, soundplayer

Edit - ANSWER: I found the solution thanks to @LexLi and @Amy; I accidentally created a .NET Core console application instead of .NET Framework. Once I remade it as a .NET Framework app it had "System.Media" available.

I'm relatively new (only a few weeks in) to learning C#, but I'm trying to make a console application text game, and I have a typewriter method I'm using to print messages to the display.

```
public static void typewriter(string s)
{
    // This method types strings out slowly.
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(s[i]);

        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

I want to add a sound when each character is typed (I have the typewriter sound already). I saw some people recommend the SoundPlayer class located in System.Media. It would look something like this:

```
SoundPlayer typewriter = new SoundPlayer();
typewriter.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/typewriter.wav";
```

My problem is, I don't seem to have access to System.Media

If I type `using System.(et cetera)`, Intellisense does not show Media as an available option. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and have .Net Framework Version 4.8 something

How can I get access to System.Media?

Here's a photo with some info to show my .Net framework and that Visual studio doesn't recognize SoundPlayer();
[image: system media not found or not containing SoundPlayer]

Comment: [You need to add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Check MSDN for documentation on that namespace.  Identify which assembly its located in.  Then add a reference to that assembly.

Comment: Hint: look up the [documentation for the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.8) under the title and the namespace, it shows "Assemblies:
System.dll, System.Windows.Extensions.dll". Right click on your project. select Add, Reference... and find one of those assemblies.

Comment: You probably created a .NET Core console application, not a .NET Framework console application (typical mistake of new guys in the field). Then you cannot use that class, unless you add a NuGet package reference to `System.Windows.Extensions`. I will suggest you create a .NET Framework console application instead, if all learning materials at your hand are still .NET Framework based.

Answer (score 1):

Check MSDN for documentation on that namespace. Identify which assembly its located in. Then add a reference to that assembly.

[Google "MSDN system.media".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media?view=netframework-4.8).  Pick a class from that namespace.  I'll use [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.8).

The documentation says that class is located in `Assemblies:
System.dll, System.Windows.Extensions.dll`.

So [add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019) to one of those assemblies.

Comment: "add a reference to each of those assemblies"? Depending on the target platform of that project (.NET Framework or .NET Core), only one of them is needed.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for the recommendation on .NET Framework vs .NET Core. I'll look into that and see if it helps. I also uploaded a screenshot to show my .NET framework version.

Comment: @RobbyHeckman The relevant framework version is in your project properties, not in VS's about window.

Comment: @RobbyHeckman The "CoreCLR" text in the output panel in your screen shot indicates .NET Core usage. So my assumption is supported.