# SoundPlayer cannot be found in visual studio code

Tags: c#, wav, soundplayer

So i am fairly new to coding and have been working on a little text based game. I wanted to add music and most sources i have found recommend using "SoundPlayer" which is supposed to be a part of "System.Media" however every time i type it into visual studio code it says that SoundPlayer does not exist in System.Media and says it is being forwarded to "System.Windows.Extensions". i have tried restoring the file through dot-net but that has not worked. Im really at a loss what it could be any help is appreciated.

Comment: This was asked just this morning.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58938947/47589